# Disable a drop down menu by a checkbox using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wrote this code to create a drop down list with multiple options. I added another checkbox to enable/disable the dropdown menu. But it doesn't work. Help me with this.

This is my HTMLcode

```
<body>
 <div id='1' value='1' class='dropdown-check-list' tabindex='100'>
  <span  class='anchor'>Select Term(s)</span>
    <ul id='items' class='items'>
        <li><input type='checkbox' />Term 1 </li>
        <li><input type='checkbox' />Term 2 </li>
        <li><input type='checkbox' />Term 3 </li>
    </ul>       
 </div>
<br/>
<br/>    
<input type ="checkbox" id='IsAssociation' /><span>your checkbox</span>
```

This is my CSS

```
<style>

.dropdown-check-list {
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-check-list .anchor {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 50px 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;

}
.dropdown-check-list .anchor:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 20%;

  -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
.dropdown-check-list .anchor:active:after {
  right: 8px;
  top: 21%;
}
 .dropdown-check-list ul.items  {
  padding: 2px;
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-top: none;

}


.dropdown-check-list ul.items li{
  list-style: none;
}

.disabled {
    pointer-events:none; 
    opacity:0.6;         
}
</style>
```

This is my Java script for dropdown menu

```
<script>
  var checkList = document.getElementById('1');
  var items = document.getElementById('items');
    checkList.getElementsByClassName('anchor')[0].onclick = function (evt) {
             if (items.classList.contains('visible')){
                 items.classList.remove('visible');
                 items.style.display = "none";
             }

             else{
                 items.classList.add('visible');
                 items.style.display = "block";
             }


          }

          items.onblur = function(evt) {
              items.classList.remove('visible');
          }
</script>
```

This is my code for disabling the drop down using the checkbox

```
 $(document).on('change', '#IsAssociation', function(){
    debugger;
    if($(this).prop('checked')){
        $('#items').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $('#items').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are applying `disabled` to `ul` tag, you have to apply `disabled` to `checkbox`

try this with `prop` instead of `attr`

```
$(document).on('change', '#IsAssociation', function(){

    if($(this).prop('checked')){
        $('#items li input').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $('#items li input').prop('disabled',false);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to disable the list. You can just disable the element that toggles the list.

```
if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
    $('.anchor').addClass('disabled');
} else {
    $('.anchor').removeClass('disabled');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add class for each list `<li>` elements.

```
<ul id='items' class='items'>
   <li><input type='checkbox' class="cBox"/>Term 1 </li>
   <li><input type='checkbox' class="cBox"/>Term 2 </li>
   <li><input type='checkbox' class="cBox"/>Term 3 </li>
</ul>

$(document).on('change', '#IsAssociation', function(){
    debugger;
    if($(this).prop('checked')){
        $('.cBox').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $('.cBox').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply disabled `attribute` to `input` and disabled `class` to `li`.

```
$('#items').find('input').prop('disabled',!this.checked);
$('#items').find('li').toggleClass('disabled',!this.checked);
```

```js
var checkList = document.getElementById('1');
var items = document.getElementById('items');
checkList.getElementsByClassName('anchor')[0].onclick = function(evt) {
  if (items.classList.contains('visible')) {
    items.classList.remove('visible');
    items.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    items.classList.add('visible');
    items.style.display = "block";
  }
}

items.onblur = function(evt) {
  items.classList.remove('visible');
}
$(function() {
  $(document).on('change', '#IsAssociation', function() {
    $('#items').find('input').prop('disabled', !this.checked);
    $('#items').find('li').toggleClass('disabled', !this.checked);
  });
  $('#IsAssociation').trigger('change');
});
```

```css
.dropdown-check-list {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-check-list .anchor {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 50px 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.dropdown-check-list .anchor:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 20%;
  -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

.dropdown-check-list .anchor:active:after {
  right: 8px;
  top: 21%;
}

.dropdown-check-list ul.items {
  padding: 2px;
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-top: none;
}

.dropdown-check-list ul.items li {
  list-style: none;
}

.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='1' value='1' class='dropdown-check-list' tabindex='100'>
  <span class='anchor'>Select Term(s)</span>
  <ul id='items' class='items'>
    <li><input type='checkbox' />Term 1 </li>
    <li><input type='checkbox' />Term 2 </li>
    <li><input type='checkbox' />Term 3 </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" id='IsAssociation' /><span>your checkbox</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#IsAssociation').change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        $('#items').prop("disabled", true);
    } else {
        $('#items').prop("disabled", false); 
    }
});
```

This should do.